# AWS deplyong ECS services through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to deploy (restart) my ECS tasks (of launch type Fargate) through `aws cli` (in last step of CI/CD).

The issue with them is that it seems I have to stop tasks, and update their status again. Still ok, but in the following command:
`aws --region regionName ecs stop-task --cluster example-cluster --task taskID`, for `--task` I either must use task UUID or task's ARN, both of which are not fully fixed.
Task's UUID changes by each revision and ARN is also a name whose last part is the revision number. Is there an identifier fully fixed that I can use as ARN?

Also, in ARN, for example if I have `nginx:4`, I cannot use "latest" instead of 4, making it completely difficult to handle and automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a mistake to use `*-task` family of commands. To deploy a service, we simply must use `update-service` command, like this:

```
aws --region regionName ecs update-service --cluster clusterName --force-new-deployment --service serviceName
```

The point is with `--force-new-deployment`, and this command is useful for those who do not use **CodeDeploy**.

Comment: when you use --force-new-deployment is there any way of stopping it.. in case that your container is broken and it is retrying to create a new task indefinitely. is there option to stop deploy and leave old container in place until fix is build and try deploy again?

Comment: @Petar Marinac  I guess not. You want to rollback, you either need to handle a manual rollbacking, by creating a new image from your last stable version and do a new dep., or you have to use one  Aws services which supports advanced deployment models (I guess OcdeDeploy but I'm not sure)